# Selecting and segmenting parts of a 3D model as part of a ModelTarget

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a 3D FBX model used in a Vuforia Unity app that I've turned into a Vuforia ModelTarget that I want to put/display many AR points on and display on AR glasses. But, a developmental challenge is that there are so many points, the user would be overwhelmed by the sheer amount of points.

As a result, we've decided to split the points that can be displayed into a series of areas/segments, where we only display the points of a selected segment.

The current approach is to segment the 3D model into multiple segmented parts, and place points on each of them. Then, switch between different 3D models and hiding points which are not part of the segment. However, we have a few issues.

1: Segmenting the model seems to cause the app to expect a cross-surface where the model does not have a cross surface (since the actual, physical model is not segmented).

2: Hiding the models in Unity, instead of removing said models (or other ways of approaching) seems computationally wasteful.

I would like to solve the 2 aforementioned problems but am not sure how to proceed. Of course, if our approach is fundamentally flawed, please also let me know. Thank you for reading and please let me know if more information is required.